How to resolve "403 Forbidden" error when trying to delete payment information in Xero API?
I am working on a project where I need to update the status of a payment invoice in Xero API to "VOIDED" and delete the associated payment information. However, when I attempt to delete the payment information, I am encountering a "403 Forbidden" error. The exact error message is:
[403] Client error: POST https://api.xero.com/api.xro/2.0/Payments/1b3b9ef2-dfb4-43d8-ba5b-435cd5cee8b4 resulted in a 403 Forbidden response.
I have checked my Xero API credentials and they seem to be in order. I'm wondering if there might be a specific permission or configuration that I'm missing in order to perform the delete operation.
Has anyone encountered a similar issue with Xero API? How can I resolve this "403 Forbidden" error and successfully delete the payment information in Xero API? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.
                    if($contract->THIRD_PARTY_SYNC ==1){
                        $apiInvoicesWithHttpInfoResponse = $apiInstance->getInvoicesWithHttpInfo($xeroTenantId, null, 'InvoiceNumber=="' . $contract->CONTRACT_NO . '"');
                        $xero_invoice_Response = $apiInvoicesWithHttpInfoResponse[0]->getInvoices()[0];
                        $apiInstance = self::minuteFlowLimitingProcessing($apiInvoicesWithHttpInfoResponse,$xeroId,$apiInstance);
                    }
                    if ($status == \XeroAPI\XeroPHP\Models\Accounting\Invoice::STATUS_PAID && !empty($filteredPayment)) {
                        $status = \XeroAPI\XeroPHP\Models\Accounting\Invoice::STATUS_AUTHORISED;
                    } elseif ($status == \XeroAPI\XeroPHP\Models\Accounting\Invoice::STATUS_PAID && $xero_invoice_Response ==null) {
                        $status = \XeroAPI\XeroPHP\Models\Accounting\Invoice::STATUS_AUTHORISED;
                    }
                    $xero_invoice->setStatus($status);
                    if($status =='VOIDED' && isset($xero_invoice_Response) &&method_exists($xero_invoice_Response, 'getPayments')){
                        $payments = $xero_invoice_Response->getPayments();
                        if (!empty($payments)) {
                            $paymentId = $payments[0]->getPaymentID();
                            $PaymentDelete = new \XeroAPI\XeroPHP\Models\Accounting\PaymentDelete;
                            $deletePayment = $apiInstance->deletePayment($xeroTenantId, $paymentId,$PaymentDelete);
                        }
                    }

I'm using API Explorer's Xero Accounting API - Payments - Delete Pyament. Nothing happens after the make request operation.
enter image description here

I think this issue is caused by Xero side at the moment. We have 2 .net framework projects that have been calling Xero.NetStandard.OAuth2.Api.AccountingApi.DeletePaymentAsync function without any issues until today. We are getting 403 error from both of the projects now. There is no update or change in their document.
https://developer.xero.com/documentation/api/accounting/payments#POST
Edit:
Their API explorer is returning the 403 error too.
https://api-explorer.xero.com/accounting/payments

Me too. Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78338240/server-refusing-to-respond-delete-payment-request-403-forbidden-xero-api

Xero API explorer is now working. Our .net projects are not receiving this error anymore too.
