Server refusing to respond Delete Payment request, 403 Forbidden [xero-api]
The https://api.xero.com/api.xro/2.0/Payments endpoint responds perfectly to requests such as get payments, get specific payments, create payments and, until yesterday, delete payments. All of this worked normally until yesterday, but since yesterday it is refusing to respond to the request that deletes a payment.
Obs.: Just reinforcing that this worked until yesterday and I didn't make any code changes. I'm using the Demo Company and all credentials are not expired.
I carried out all possible tests using this endpoint, I even used another app, another tenant, checked the spopes, reconnected numerous times and the result is the same: the only request refused is the delete payment.
I get the response 403 Forbidden. I also made a bad request to see if the server would respond to me and, yes, I received the message that it was a Bad Request. But when the delete request is correctly configured, the server refuses to respond to it. To make sure I wasn't mistaken, I used Xero's postman to perform the test and the postman itself returned to me that "The request was a legal request, but the server is refusing to respond to it."

I have the same problem. The scope is correct. I have a payment ID from an invoice, and when I post it to delete it, I get a 403 error. I am reusing code that was successful with this in the past.

Seems to be a Xero problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78338027/how-to-resolve-403-forbidden-error-when-trying-to-delete-payment-information-i

it's working again
